# Loading shapefile to a specific table in postgis using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I have already created a geometry table in postgis. I want to load several shapefiles into that table using ogr2ogr. But I didn't find the parameter which could specify that table.

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=db and so on" shapefile.shp
```

That's it. How can I add some parameter to specify the table?

Answer (score 21):

To be explicit about nickves' answer:

```
ogr2ogr -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=db" shapefile.shp -nln mytable
```

Comment: (-nln is also working for appending to existing tables in geopackages)

Answer (score 12):

http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

use the flag -nln to specify the name of your target table

Comment: Another Question regarding that:   Can I add some parameter using this command. Such as the user defined ID ?